# I am trying to set a @keyframe animation in css, however when I look on Inspect in my browser, they have strike-through lines?

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe, strikethrough

> **My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to SPACE </title>
    <link rel="icon" href="planeticon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexspace.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="sun"></div>
        <div class="earth"></div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

> So this is my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(starbackground.jpg);
}
 
.container {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin: 200px auto;
position: relative;
padding:40px;
}

.sun {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: URL(sun2.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.earth {
    width: 40px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url(earth4.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px 2px #000000cc;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-name: slide;
}

@keyframes slide {
    

    50%{
        left: calc(100%-40px);
        top: calc(100%-40px);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

And this is what it shows in Inspect:   [key frame problem][1]      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmT6I.png

I've read that strikethrough lines means that some other element is overriding its importance, however I'm struggling to figure this one out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the correct form is calc(100% - 40px). you have to use the space [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())

Comment: strikethrough means it is overwritten, or the syntax is not correct. I think you need a space before and after the minus in your calc: `calc(100% - 40px);`

Comment: @GertB. the space must be also after the minus

Comment: @Sfili_81 woops, indeed, my mistake - edited.

Comment: It was the spaces, small things change everything lol  thanks so much guys